# How to get sum of integers from text file in bash

Tags: bash

Hi I just started learning bash script, and I need your help with this task. I have to sum all integers (from file.text) which comes before definite word, for example word "point":

"Today I got 5 points. However I should got 7 but, 2 point lost."

So I have to get 7 (5+2). Of course ending of word should not matter, either if it will end with "s" (point**s**) or something else, doesn't matter.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use `grep` or `awk` to find the number before `point`. Put it in a variable, then add it toa total variable.

Comment: does the file contain multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

`awk -v RS='[0-9]+' '{n+=RT};END{print n} file.text`

[Found this snippet here with a web search engine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205936/how-can-i-quickly-sum-all-numbers-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** approach:

Let's say `file.txt` contains:

```
Today I got 5 points. However I should got 7 but, 2 point lost.
Today I got 5 points. However I should got 7 but, 2 point lost.
```

The command:

```
awk -F ' point' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){ match($i,/[0-9]+$/); sum+=substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH) }}
     END {print sum}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
14
```

---

`-F ' point'` - `point` string with preceding whitespace is treated as field separator

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pcregrep` and `awk` to achieve the problem (tested on OSX)

```
$ cat file.txt
Today I got 5 points. However I should got 7 but, 2 point lost.
$ cat file.txt | pcregrep -Mo '\d+ (?=points?)' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
7
```

Or turn into a script file by creating a file named `sum.sh` that includes following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
pcregrep -Mo '\d+ (?=points?)' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Change file mode:

```
$ chmod +x sum.sh
```

Then, run

```
$ ./sum.sh < file.txt
7
```